# Not able to comment using comment form of comfortable mexican sofa and comfy_blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I used the  gem 'comfortable_mexican_sofa', '~> 1.10.0',gem 'comfy_blog', '~> 1.0.0' in rails4 application. When i post comment after filling the comment form, it shows a message "can't be blank" after every field. thus I am not able to comment. Rest all are working fine. but I need comment form also.

Comment: Do you get any warnings about `Unpermitted parameters` in the log?

Comment: No,I can also see a message "Failed to create comment" when I move to blogs admin. In command line, there is a warning also-" WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the source of `ComfyBlog`. The posted parameters to create the comment are stored in the `blog_comment` key. But the controller is fetching the `comment` key:

```
# comfy-blog / app / controllers / blog / comments_controller.rb
# Line 30

def comment_params
  params.fetch(:comment, {}).permit(:author, :email, :content)
end             ^
                |___ Should be :blog_comment
```

I've added the issue to their github page. https://github.com/comfy/comfy-blog/issues/24

Comment: I tried downloading the 'comfortable_mexican_sofa' from github and  instead of adding gem I added the code of comfy_blog in CMS app directly and found that the comment form is working. but when i  make a rails 4 app and add both the gems, comment form does not work.  Why is it so??? If it is working otherwise, it should be working with the gems also.

Comment: hey...same problem came suddenly in the downloaded one also....thanks your solution worked for me...thanks a lot :)